# Getting "Permission denied" on dirname and basename

Tags: linux, shell, dirname

That's all. They just won't work for me. What did I do wrong this time?

```
    # nquo is: /home/bryan/renametest/C D/y z

    # script:
    dirn=dirname "$nquo"
    echo "dirn $dirn"
    bnam=basename "$nquo"
    echo "bnam $bnam"
```

Run result:

```
    ./script3.sh: 208: /home/bryan/renametest/C D/y z: Permission denied
    dirn 
    ./script3.sh: 208: /home/bryan/renametest/C D/y z: Permission denied
    bnam
```

Comment: you can check the permissions of the file/directory with `ls -ld "$nquo"`

Comment: Is this bash?  If so you are missing `$(...)` or backticks around `dirname` and `basename` invocations.  Plus, working with filenames containing spaces is very tricky.

Comment: @JimGarrison No, it isn't tricky at all if you know what you do.

Comment: @glglgl: It requires care and attention to detail.  It is much harder to handle names with spaces, etc., than names without.  Or, put another way, when the names contain no spaces, you can get away with sloppy techniques that happen to work only because there are no spaces in the names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I always put `"`...`"` around my variables and everything works.

Comment: @glglgl: That is perhaps 95% of the battle; always use double quotes around the variable names. You still have to exercise caution. For those of us who learned shell programming when spaces in file names were abhorred and such files ignored or renamed, there is culture shock. Most of my scripts written in the last 10 years will work with names-with-spaces, but probably not all. Names with newlines are a good deal harder to manage because you can't pass them around using one-line-is-one-name conventions. The utilities don't always help. Yes, it can be done, most of the time. No, it ain't easy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's right; a little bit of care is necessary in these extreme cases. I try to use the `-0` options wherever possible - but that is not always possible...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it stands, your script is trying to run the file named in `$nquo` first with the environment variable `dirn` set to the value `dirname`, and then with the variable `bnam` set to the value `basename`. Since it is not executable, you get the error message about not being able to execute the file.

You presumably intended to run the commands on the name of the file, which requires either back-ticks or (preferably) `$(...)` around it:

```
dnam=$(dirname "$nquo")
bnam=$(basename "$nquo")
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you once again Jonathan.

Comment: this answer is also safe my time