# sed: how can I replace an identifier/key word in a file with a file name?

Tags: file, sed, replace, file-io, find

I have a parent directory that contains a succession of daughter directories called:

```
1
2
3
4 # <-- This one is used in an example below.
...
```

Each daughter directory contains a file called `input` and a grandchild directory called `data`.  Within "data" is a file named by multiplying the daughter directory name by 1000.  For example:

```
Parent directory / daughter directory #4 / input

Parent directory / daughter directory #4 / data / 4000.dat
```

**Here is what I need to do**:
Within each `input` file, replace the term "old_file_name" with the name of the file in the corresponding `data` directory.  So in the example above, I need to find the term "old_file_name" and replace it with "4000.dat."

Here is what I have tried, with notes on what I want to be doing to each `input` file:

```
find_replace_old_file_name="old_file_name"

i=$((daughter)); # This is the directories called "1," "2," "3," etc.
daughter2=$((1000*daughter)) # Multiply by 1000 to get correct filename in /data.
l=$(sed "${i}q;d" parent/$daughter/data/$daughter2.dat) # Get filename of file in /data.
echo ${l%}

find parent/${i} -type f -exec sed -i -e "s/${find_replace_old_file_name}/${l}/g" {} +
```

I am doing something wrong at the "l=" step because in each `input` file, the term `old_file_name` is being replaced with the contents of the .dat files, not their names.  So in the example above, I want `4000.dat` to replace `old_file_name` in the corresponding `input` file, but instead I'm getting the contents of `4000.dat.` Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the etiquette for responding to one's own question, but thought I'd post a solution in case it's useful for other people.

I came across this question ([Getting "Permission denied" on dirname and basename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803227/getting-permission-denied-on-dirname-and-basename)) and adapted the answer to replace my "l=" line:

```
l=$(basename parent/$daughter/data/*.dat)
```

It solved my problem.  I get the name of the file and can now put it in the `input` file.